# Using text to speech api in windows 8.1

Tags: text-to-speech, windows-8.1, voice

I am creating a windows 8.1 app using text to speech api. So now my question is that how to change the age or gender of the voice and if a certain voice is not installed on the client machine how can I supply that voice with my app?

Answer (score 1):

[Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn278951)

[Speech synthesis MSDN sample for Windows 8.1](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Speech-synthesis-sample-6e07b218)

Currently there's no variety of age is available for voice, but you can change gender of voice by setting [`VoiceGender`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.media.speechsynthesis.voicegender) enum.

You don't need to bundle the voice with the app. The OS contains all the framework libraries.

Comment: When I am checking for installed voices on my machine. I get three female voices and no male voices. I am using windows 8.1. If this case arises in my client machine, how can I supply male voices with my app?

Comment: Don't you get male voice when you set `VoiceGender` enum?